# Removing old cache files - command help

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface, shell, command

I'm trying to write a command to help clear up old cache asset files. The files are always either `.css`,`.javascript`,`.css.gzip` or `.javascript.gzip` and i want to delete all files older than 2 days old.

I started with this command to test before passing to `exec rm`:

```
find /home/*/tmp/cache/* -mtime +2 -type f -name '*.css.gzip' -o -name '*.javascript.gzip' -o -name '*.javascript' -o -name '*.css'
```

This returns all the files i want deleting, so i've added `rm` making the command:

```
find /home/*/tmp/cache/* -mtime +2 -type f -name '*.css.gzip' -o -name '*.javascript.gzip' -o -name '*.javascript' -o -name '*.css' -exec rm {} \;
```

Nothing is actually getting deleted though, i tried making the `rm` command `rm -i` and there were no prompts, as if nothing is actually being passed to rm.

Any ideas?

FWIW this is on a CentOS 5 box

Comment: Your command seems ok. I tried it on my system. I got prompted when added `-i`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that adding `-exec ...` to the end of all those `-o` flags is tripping up precedence of AND vs OR, eg it's finding everything that is *.css.gzip OR *.javascript.gzip OR *.javascript OR (*.css AND delete it) so it only removes *.css but finds all the other files but does nothing with them.  Incidentally it also means that your type and mtime flags are only applying to *.javascript.gzip.

Use

```
find /home/*/tmp/cache/* -mtime +2 -type f \( -name '*.css.gzip' -o -name '*.javascript.gzip' -o -name '*.javascript' -o -name '*.css' \) -exec rm {} \;
```

in order to force it to find all files with mtime +2 AND type f AND (all the different filename options) AND delete them.

To see this in action, replace -exec ... with -print in both your version and my version with ().

Comment: This is a good argument for the xargs approach too.

Comment: @Phil: even then, without the parentheses it would have found directories named *.javascript or files less than 2 days old.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing rm to echo and see what it's doing. If nothing is returned, remove the echo and you'll probably remember changing the command slightly before adding the rm :).

Comment: switching the rm to echo it just displays a single filename, are you implying you've spotted something wrong though or just suggesting that as a debug?

Answer (score 0):

Take your first command, pipe to xargs rm. I generally like to account for filenames with spaces as well so try this:

```
find /home/*/tmp/cache/* -mtime +2 -type f -name '*.css.gzip' -o -name '*.javascript.gzip' -o -name '*.javascript' -o -name '*.css' -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

Comment: none of the filenames have spaces so not sure what i gain from this approach?

Comment: in that case you don't get anything above just using xargs.

Answer (score 0):

Try with xargs instead:

```
find /home/*/tmp/cache/* -mtime +2 -type f -name '*.css.gzip' -o -name '*.javascript.gzip' -o -name '*.javascript' -o -name '*.css' -print0 | xargs -0p rm
```

the `-p` argument to xargs will prompt you on each batch of files to be deleted.  If that works ok, you can remove the `-p` to just rm the entire delete at once.

The `-print0` / `-0` combo uses nulls instead of spaces for delimiters to ensure that odd filenames (such as filenames with spaces) are handled correctly.

Comment: Not sure what counts as an odd filename - all are similar to this type of format cache-1289825172-4e1d9990b3fb6da7da81175b33b6097e.javascript

Comment: What do you see when using `-p` in xargs?  That will tell you if your find command is passing the list of filenames you expect.

Comment: output is: `/bin/echo /home/user/tmp/cache/front/assets/cache-1294923239-5802bb1a1cefeb43a797258e1f6ceef9.css ?...`